# Is $f(x)=x^2 \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ continuously differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=x^2 \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$ on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ and $f(0)=0$

Show that this function is not continuously differentiable in $\mathbb R$.

I don't know how to show differentiability in $\mathbb R$ using the fraction definition of a limit, and what is the appropriate condition for checking continuous differentiability.

Comment: Do you know what continuous differentiability is?

Comment: I only know that f must be differentiable on R and f' must be continuos on R, but not sure if there is a specific numeric result I can use to get a contradiction

Comment: Do you know the definition of *continuous differentiability*?

Comment: A function is continuously differentiable if is satisfies the conditions I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is the derivative: $f'(x) = 2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.  The second part (the cosine) doesn't converge to anything @ $x = 0$.  Which means the derivative is doing "strange" things near $x = 0$ which is because the $sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is oscillating wildly near $x = 0$--which is fine because the $x^2$ is making it smaller and smaller in amplitude, but as far as the derivative is concerned it's still going back and forth between positive and negative slope.

Answer (score 3):

Find the derivative.  You should get a term that approaches $0$ as $x\to0$ and another term that oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ as $x\to 0$.  Because of the second term, the derivative approaches no limit as $x\to 0$, and so is not continuous, despite the fact that $f'(0)$ is defined, as can be shown by taking the limit of the difference quotient.

Comment: Actually I think that term approaches $2$, not $0$.

Comment: @Jared no term approaches 2... What Michael said is correct!

Comment: @ah11950 perhaps I did the derivative wrong, but one of the two terms should be $2xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, which should approach $2$ since $sin(x) = x$ for small $x$ and that would give $2x\frac{1}{x} = 2$.

Comment: Indeed there's a mistake here. Firstly $\sin x = x$ for small $x$ is very imprecise, but moreover as $x$ is getting small, $1/x$ is not! Remember that you can bound $|2x\sin (1/x)|$ by $|2x|$. Now use the squeeze rule.

Comment: @ah11950 yeah you're right.  I don't really think $sin(x) = x$ for small $x$ is so imprecise, the problem is, as you said, $\frac{1}{x}$ isn't approaching $0$, so a small angle approximation isn't even close to being valid.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Jared : You should learn to write $\sin x$ or $\sin(x)$ instead of $sin(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Alright, I figured it out, duly noted, $\sin(x)$ does look better than $sin(x)$--but you'll never see my write any function without parenthesis (unless I'm purposefully not putting the parameter for brevity, like $\ddot{f} + \dot{f} = 0$)

Answer (score 2):

At $0$; $f'(0)=0$ (proof?). If $x\neq 0$; $f'(x)=2x\sin x^{-1}-\cos x^{-1}$. Does $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ exist?

Comment: If you find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ does not exist, then you need not compute $f'(0)$ at all.

Comment: That is true, yes. I just wanted to observe $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem. $|f'(0)| = |x^2\cdot \sin(1/x) / x| \leq |x| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. So, $f'(0) = 0$. $f'(x) = 2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$ otherwise. Now, take the limit as we go to zero. We have $\lim f'(x)$ does not exist. Simply choose $\epsilon = 1$ and $x = (2\pi n)^{-1}$, $y = [(2n+1) \pi]^{-1}$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Then $2=|\cos(1/x)-\cos(1/y)| < |\cos(1/x) - 0| + |0 - \cos(1/y)| < 2$ and we have a contradiction. This should be enough to fill in the details.